# Hypernym for injured and dead

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage, hyphenation

I'm working on some project that deals with natural disasters. I need to find the most proper word that can be used to refer to someone who either was injured or died in a disaster.

Can I use *casualty*? Or maybe *involved* is better?

Comment: fatality is another option

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps *[victim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/victim)* is the word you are searching for:-

> 1. a person who suffers from a destructive or injurious action or agency: a victim of an automobile accident.

Comment: I think that in the end i'll stick with casualty - [i found this on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualty_(person))

Comment: @royv, possibly you are right. _Victim_ seems to be applied in a rather expansive manner nowadays.